# Get javascript string out of ruby hash sent in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ruby, ruby-hash

So, I have a ruby program that takes a hash and turns it into a JSON string (lets say the hash is #FFFFFF) and that JSON string is sent to a javascript  program where it needs to get #FFFFFF out of the JSON string, i've tried JSON.parse(); to no avail, and JSON.stringify(); only returns this `"{\"color\":\"#FFFFFF\"}"` how do I get it to return just #FFFFFF in a javascript string?

Comment: How are you passing this to javascript?

Comment: @charlietfl web sockets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the JSON originates from a Ruby hash is irrelevant. You have to `JSON.parse` the JSON string — but! then you *also* have to access the `.color` property of the resulting object

```js
let json = '{"color":"#FFFFFF"}'
let data = JSON.parse(json)
console.log(data.color)
// #FFFFFF
```